# TeamCity 8.1 How to tell build configurations to use separate copies of VCS Root

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

In TeamCity 7, there was an option in the VCS root setting that allowed you to specify that each build configuration should create it's own working directory with it's own copy of the files from the VCS root, even if multiple configurations are pointing to the same branch.

I can't find this setting anymore. Has the option been removed?

I have two configurations pointing to my develop branch and both are sharing the same working directory on the build agent.

I'm using Git as my VCS root.

The VCS root is defined in a template.

Answer (score 0):

In checkout options, (Advanced options), in Checkout Settings, you can have a Checkout directory that is a Custom path. You can use parameters to have a different path for each build. We use that in ours configs, the custom path includes the branch name in the path, among others values.